# How to determine in lambda where request is coming from?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, invoke

I have a AWS setup containing an api gateway resource and a lambda function.
I need to determine in lambda function if request is coming from direct invocation or through api gateway invocation.

How would this be possible?

For now I tried to find something suitable on google, but without success unfortunatly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure you've noticed that a new Lambda function is declared as follows:

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  // Your code goes here
}
```

The event object here contains information regarding the invocation of your Lambda Function. For example, if your lambda is triggered by an upload to S3 this will contain information about the object being uploaded for example or in your case, it will contain API Gateway information.

See more documentation on AWS Lambda's integration with other services [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-services.html).

Comment: I feel so dump right now, thank you for solution :)